# Combining two regular expression c++0x

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have a text where a date can look like this: `2011-02-02` or like this: `02/02/2011`, this is what I have been written so far, and my question is, if there is a nice way of combining these two regular expressions into one?

```
std::regex reg1("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})");

std::regex reg2("(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})");

smatch match;
if(std::regex_search(item, match, reg1))
{
       Date.wYear  = atoi(match[1].str().c_str());
       Date.wMonth = atoi(match[2].str().c_str());
       Date.wDay   = atoi(match[3].str().c_str());
}
else if(std::regex_search(item, match, reg2))
{
       Date.wYear  = atoi(match[3].str().c_str());
       Date.wMonth = atoi(match[2].str().c_str());
       Date.wDay   = atoi(match[1].str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: Some regex syntaxes have named groups. PCRE does, but I don't think it supports duplicate names. Perhaps the question is: do any of the regex variants on C++0x support duplicate named groups?

Comment: I don't see the benefit. This is easier to read than the combined regular expression. This benefits maintenance which is a factor that is not to underestimate. This code can even be read without documentation - combining it, you need to document the "monster-regex".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine the two regexes together by `|`. Since only one of the `|` can be matched, we can then concatenate capture groups of different parts and think them as a whole.

```
std::regex reg1("(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})|(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})");
std::smatch match;

if(std::regex_search(item, match, reg1)) {
    std::cout << "Year=" << atoi(match.format("$1$6").c_str()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Month=" << atoi(match.format("$2$5").c_str()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Day=" << atoi(match.format("$3$4").c_str()) << std::endl;
}
```

(Unfortunately C++0x's regex does not support named capture group, otherwise I'd suggest loop over an array of regexes using named capture instead.)

Comment: @Jörgen: Ask ECMA. C++'s regex is based on ECAMScript (Javascript)'s regex flavor.